# PHP/HTML- checkbox

Tags: php, html, hidden

I want to get ids from one page to another but only those ids I checked.
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="del_novica_admin_sql.php" methos="POST">

    <table border="2">


        <?php 
        $st=0;
        include 'povezava_na_bazo.php';
        include 'session.php';



        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM novice_i ni INNER JOIN uporabniki u ON ni.id_u=u.id_u 
            WHERE id_i='$_SESSION[igralec]' AND $_POST[vrsta]='1'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['up_ime']; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['novica']; ?></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="zbrisi<?php echo $st;?>" value="<?php echo $row['id_ni'];?>" ><br></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $st++;
        }

        ?> 




    </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="st" value="<?php echo $st; ?>" >
         <input type="submit">  

      </form>









</body>
```

And page 2, del_novica_admin_sql.php is the name of 2nd page:

```
    <?php
include 'povezava_na_bazo.php';

$sts=0;
$st = $_POST['st'];
$z='zbrisi'.$sts;
echo $z;

while ($sts < $st)
{    
    echo $_POST[$z];
    $sts++;
}

?>
```

First time I post a question, hope you guys know what I asked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group checkboxes by giving them the same name and appending square brackets:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="zbrisi[]" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="zbrisi[]" value="value2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="zbrisi[]" value="value3" />
```

PHP will parse such parameters automatically and store them in an array:

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['zbrisi']; // Note: name has no sq. brackets here
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
    echo $checkbox;
}
// output: 'value1value3' when boxes 1 and 3 were checked
```

Assuming you selected boxes 1 and 3, the array will have this content:

```
$checkboxes = array(
    0 => 'value1',
    1 => 'value3'
);
```

---

You can also give the array members indexes (other than 0,1,2,...) with this syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox[box1]" value="value1" />
```

In PHP:

```
echo $_POST['checkbox']['box1']; // will echo 'value1'
```

---

Besides, this works for all types of input.
PHP will parse the request (this works for query strings with `$_GET[]` too) and join parameters with the array syntax (`[]` for indexed, or `[someindex]` for associative arrays).